# Link fields in User Admin list

Tags: custom-field, admin, users

I am using admin columns to show my custom fields for all the users. I have them displayed like this:
[image]

Basically I want to add the link to the user edit page under the "Custom Field" column rather than the Username area.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using admin columns" ? Is it custom code? Some plugin?

Comment: @Rarst yes, it's a plugin called admin columns. Is there a way I can link customly?

Comment: In such case it is better aimed at plugin's support routes. You are unlikely to get good plugin-specific answers here (given there are tens of thousands of them) and they are considered off topic for that reason.

Comment: @Rarst I am wondering if there is anyway I can edit the columns myself. How would I go about doing that without a plugin

Comment: There should be existing questions on that around, or you could ask a new one about making such customization with code.